# Limit number of products on WooCommerce search results page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In my functions.php I have the following line of code:

```
// Display 48 products per page.
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', create_function( '$cols', 'return 48;' ), 20 );
```

This limits the number of products shown at the shop page and the category pages. However this will not work on the results page when I'm searching on a product tag. What did I wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

This will change a limit of search result for the product.I hop this will be helpful to you.

```
function searchfilter($query) {

    if ($query->is_search && !is_admin() ) {
        $query->set('post_type',array('product'));
        $query->set('posts_per_page',25);
    }

return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchfilter');
```

**Case 2 :Create your own**

To customise the search results template create a new file in the theme called search.php, this will only be used on the search page.

```
<?php
/**
 * Search Results Template File
 */
get_header(); ?>
    <header>
        <h1>Search Results: &quot;<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>&quot;</h1>
        <br>
    </header>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) :  // results found?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <article>
            <h2><?php the_title();  ?></h2>
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            <p> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">View</a> </p>
        </article>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else :  // no results?>
    <article>
        <h1>No Results Found.</h1>
    </article>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: thanks. However it did not help (yet). It is still displaying more than the quantity set (12).

Comment: mmm, it looks like that when I click on a tag (at the frontend) it works perfectly. When I use the widget WooCommerce Product Search it don't.....